# Curtailing Aggressive Lazy Wildcards

Tags: java, regex, xml, wildcard

I have a couple patterns that parse a simple text file for information, and builds an employee object with the data. There are two types of employees: Full time and Hourly. I've leaned on Lazy Wildcards to parse out XML data. My main issue is that the Lazy Wildcard is being more aggressive than intended. The fulltime Pay Record pattern (patternPRF) Lazy Wildcard is starting in the hourly payRecord (at 2), then taking everything until it hits  in the next payRecord. Is there anyway I could reign the Wildcard in and say 'you've gone too far' or something to keep it restricted to the employees with all the fulltime attributes(monthlyIncome & month tages as opposed to payHours&payRate)?

Text file to be parsed:

```
<payRecord id="10">
    <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID> //matcher.group(2) starts here
    <PayHours>30</PayHours>
    <PayRate>15</PayRate>
</payRecord>
<payRecord id="11">
    <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
    <MonthlyIncome>3500</MonthlyIncome> //ends here
    <NumMonths>8</NumMonths>
</payRecord>
<payRecord id="12">
    <EmployeeID>3
    </EmployeeeID>
    <MonthlyIncome>5000</MonthlyIncome>
    <NumMonths>6</NumMonths>
</payRecord>
```

Regex Pattern:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\s", ""); //remove all whitespace     

//payrecord hourly
patternPRH = Pattern.compile(
        "<payRecordid=\"(.*?)\">" //1 id
                + "<EmployeeID>(.*?)</EmployeeID>" //2 EmpID
                + "<PayHours>(.*?)</PayHours>" //3 payHours
                + "<PayRate>(.*?)</PayRate>" //4 payRate
);
//payrecord fulltime
patternPRF = Pattern.compile(
        "<payRecordid=\"(.*?)\">"//1 id 
                + "<EmployeeID>(.*?)</EmployeeID>"//2 EmployeeID <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
                + "<MonthlyIncome>(.*?)</MonthlyIncome>"//3 MonthlyIncome
                + "<NumMonths>(.*?)</NumMonths>"//4 numMonths
);
```

As a side note, I'm not able to use any XML parsing classes unfortunately, as part of a class requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fond of negative regex. For example `[^"]*` will match as many characters as it can that *aren't* quotes.

Consider using something like:

```
patternPRH = Pattern.compile(
    "<payRecordid=\"([^\"]*)\">" //1 id
    + "<EmployeeID>([^<]*)</EmployeeID>" //2 EmpID
    + "<PayHours>([^<]*)</PayHours>" //3 payHours
    + "<PayRate>([^<]*)</PayRate>" //4 payRate
);
```

Comment: This is closest to what I had in mind. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, you can limit your match to

```
(\d+)
```

instead of

```
(.*?)
```

for payRecordId, EmployeeID.

Doing so, the match group won't take anything than number, and make your regex work as you except